# How to save selected items from a listview to SQlite then view them on another page with titles?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

I am building an android application (new to this)

There are several topics such as Cars, Phones, and laptops each having sublistings such as Mercedes, Chevrolet; Iphone,Samsung; Dell ,Toshiba. They are set in Listviews.

Now when the user clicks on Mercedes let's say I want this input to be saved in another activity in a list called Cars.Then he would select a phone and it would be saved permenatly in the latter activity in a list called Phones etc.

I have researched alot about SQLite databases but i still didnt hit any wins
Any quick help is appreciated.

Comment: I can't understand your question clearly. You want to create an SQLite database and save data into it as user clicks on any item. The item will be saved in its respective type and then can be viewed inside Another activity. Is this what you want or something else ??

Comment: Can you provide images of this listview?

Comment: Yes Varun Kumar this is exactly what i want